# Override UILabel's setText method?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I'd like to override `UILabel`'s `setText` method but I'm not sure that:

**A)** it's possible, and 
 **B)** if maybe there's a better way to achieve what I'm trying to accomplish.

I have a subclass of `UIView` that has a `UILabel` property as one of its sub-views. I'd like to know when the `UILabel`'s "text" property changes so I can adjust the size of the rounded rect behind it. If I owned `UILabel` I'd just override `setText`...but `UILabel` is Apple's and its implementation is hidden.

So, how should I be going about this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`Key-Value Observing`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) to track changes to the `UILabel.text` property.  The approach involves three steps:

1) Registering to observe the property, when you load the view

```
[label addObserver:inspector
             forKeyPath:@"text"
                 options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew |
                            NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld)
                    context:NULL];
```

2) Receiving a notification about any changes:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
              ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqual:@"text"]) {
        // put your logic here
    }
    // be sure to call the super implementation
    // if the superclass implements it
    [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath
                ofObject:object
                 change:change
                 context:context];
}
```

3) De-registering the observation whenever you aren't interested any more:

```
[label removeObserver:inspector forKeyPath:@"text"];
```

Comment: Is it possible to add a Key Value Observer to a subclassed uilabel for example in initWithFrame: then observe that value in the same subclassed uilabel? I get the following error when I try it: `An -observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: message was received but not handled.`

Answer (score 11):

Subclasses of UILabel can override the setText method quite easily. I'm not really sure why this hasn't yet been included as a legitimate answer on this 4 year old question.

```
- (void) setText:(NSString *)text
{
    [super setText:text];

    [self sizeToFit];
}
```

Comment: I had to remove `sizeToFit` in order to get mine to work, otherwise the text wouldn't be visible.

Comment: Wouldn't you have to subclass UILabel for this solution to work?

Comment: @eleven Yes, this is for subclassed `UILabel`s only.

Comment: Still, Matt's answer is the only way for this to work if you don't want to subclass UILabel and rather implement the behavior in a UILabel extension.

Answer (score 6):

Matt answer is good for Objective-C, but doesn't work in Swift (normal, it didn't existed when he answered), the accepted answer from notnoop does work in swift, even though it is more complicated, just to give another idea in swift you can use the **didSet**:

```
class MyLabel: UILabel {

  override var text: String? {
      didSet {
        if let text = text {
          println("the new text is: \(text)")
        } else {
          println("the text has been set to nil")
        }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on Drix answer, I think this is a more correct approach (using `set` instead of `didSet`):

```
class UnreadCountLabel: UILabel {

    override var text: String? {
        set {
            if let newValue = newValue where !newValue.isEmpty {
                super.text = "  \(newValue)  "
                self.hidden = false
            } else {
                super.text = newValue
                self.hidden = true
            }
        }

        get {
            return super.text
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you just using a rounded rectangle as the background for the Label? If that is the case, you can look into using UIIMage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight. This will take an image you've created that has a left and top repeating section with a width you specify and automatically stretch it to your width.

If not, Key-Value observing is the way to go. Just to cover another option--this is like "playing with fire," as Apple programmer Evan Doll said in one of his Stanford lectures--you can use method swizzling to exchange one method implementation for another.

```
void method_exchangeImplementations(Method m1, Method m2);
```

In this case, you want to tweak the implementation of setText, but you also want to call the original setText in UILabel. So you could exchange setText with setTextAndUpdateSize, and inside setTextAndUpdateSize do what setText does originally plus add on a little more. If you are confused or think this is a bad idea, it probably is. You can get a Method object to pass into method_exchangeImplementations by calling class_getInstanceMethod([NSSTring class], @selector (methodName).

Once your method swizzle has been called once, inside your new method you can then call the old implementation of setText from within the new one by using, yes, setTextAndUpdateSize. It's confusing and not recommended, but it works. A good example can be found in [the developer sample code.](http://developer.apple.com/SampleCode/MethodReplacement/listing3.html)

Comment: This is an interesting approach that I wasn't aware of...but in this case I think I'll stick with the mainstream... good to know though. thx.

Comment: Subclassing and is a much easier way of overriding a method, unless you can't control the class of the UILabel.

Answer (score 0):

**I pulled of Method Swizzling in Swift 2.0. Changing the font of the entire application by swapping the implementation of setText method of the label.**

*Copy the code in app delegate and use the customSetText to make application level changes*

```
   // MARK: - Method Swizzling

extension UILabel {
    public override class func initialize() {
        struct Static {
            static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
        }

        // make sure this isn't a subclass
        if self !== UILabel.self {
            return
        }

        dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
            let originalSelector = Selector("setText:")
            let swizzledSelector = Selector("customSetText:")

            let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, originalSelector)
            let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, swizzledSelector)

            let didAddMethod = class_addMethod(self, originalSelector, method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod))

            if didAddMethod {
                class_replaceMethod(self, swizzledSelector, method_getImplementation(originalMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod))
            } else {
                method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Custom set text method for UI Label

    func customSetText(text: String) {
        self.customSetText(text)
        //set custom font to all the labels maintaining the size UILabel
        self.font = UIFont(name: "Lato-LightItalic", size: self.font.pointSize)
    }
}
```